# What does the code below mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how does the code below work to do because I have found this on a website for getting a file's name but I don't fully understand how it works:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    localStorage["fname"] = files[0].name; //save the name for future use
}
```

Is the code above correct for a form code like below:

```
  <form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >
    <p><input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></p>
<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>
```

Comment: What about it specifically is unclear to you?

Comment: Well, the evt.target.files, is that suppose to match the target name I already have in the form or is it's own keyword. also what about files, is that suppose to match the name attribute of the file input? Should it be evt.upload_target.fileImage? Where does 'fname' come from in the localStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is bound is probably bound the to the `change` event of that file input field.

So lets break this down.

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
```

When a function is bound as a listener to an event, typically an object that represents that event is passed in.  This is the `evt` variable being accepted by this event handler function.

```
var files = evt.target.files;
```

For DOM events, event objects typically have a property called `target` that is a reference to the DOM element that triggered the event.  So `evt.target` returns the file input element.

And file input elements have a property called `files`, that is an array of file objects that the user has chosen (note that there may be only one file chosen, but it's still going to be an array with only one item).  That line assigns that array to the `files` local variable.

```
localStorage["fname"] = files[0].name;
```

`localStorage` is a persistent key value store (sorta like cookies) introduced as part of HTML5.  `"fname"` is the key we are storing a value under.  And `files[0].name` gets the first file object, and returns its `name` property, effectively getting the name of the selected file.  This value is then stored, so that even if you refresh the page you can read back that last chosen filename just by running `localStorage["fname"]`

Comment: Ok, that is a great explanation, I understand it fully thanks :)

Comment: Probably worth adding that the features used are only available in recent browsers, they will fail in not very old ones.